# App force close due to uncaught exception

Tags: android, exception

I'm new to Java so, I think in order to prevent this error from appearing I'll have to write a Handler thread? Using `try` and `catch`? How do i do this?

Here's the code to help you out.

Thanks :)

```
package android.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidActivity extends Activity{

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start_CoolWhapp);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want help, you need to post the content of the LogCat that shows the exception. Also, the code for the thread that throws it would be nice :) Also one thing I would do is replace the "view.getContext()" in the intent with "AndroidActivity.this", it may be what causes the problem, whatever it is.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there are a few things

First make sure all activities are in your manifest file like so:

```
<activity android:name=".AndroidActivity " android:label="@string/activity_name"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activity2" android:label="@string/another_activity_name"></activity>
```

You may need more attributes than that but that's the basics.

I do not know why you need "startActivityForResult" as I cannot see the code but if it is just another activity with a layout with Views then you can alter your code like so:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent); //you do not have to use CurrentActivity.this to use startActivity however I am trying to show where context is coming from
```

Make sure activity2 has a layout and that the layout exists.

Comment: These are good advices, but the "CurrentActivity.this" is not needed in the call to startActivity.

Comment: I know its just illustrate the point to show where context is coming from.

Comment: Thanks to Guillaume for his input too.